React + socket.io actualizando productos en todos los navegadores
Buenas estoy utilizando React y socket.io para que el estado de los productos se actualicen en tiempo real en todos los navegadores de los usuarios.
Mi componente Products:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ContentLoader from 'react-content-loader';
import { FaCartPlus, FaRegHeart } from 'react-icons/fa';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const ProductLoader = () => (
  <ContentLoader height={280} width="100%">
    <rect x="3%" y="3" rx="10" ry="10" width="94%" height="180" />
    <rect x="3%" y="190" rx="0" ry="0" width="94%" height="20" />
    <rect x="3%" y="215" rx="0" ry="0" width="80%" height="20" />
    <rect x="3%" y="242" rx="0" ry="0" width="90%" height="20" />
  </ContentLoader>
);

  const Productos = ({ categoryId }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [initialLoad, setInitialLoad] = useState(true);
  const limitPerPage = 18; // Número de productos por página

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io('http://00.000.0000:5178');
  
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to Socket.IO server');
      socket.emit('getProductos', page, limitPerPage);
    });
  
    socket.on('productos', (productos) => {
      setData((prevData) => (page === 1 ? productos.data : [...prevData, ...productos.data]));
      setLoading(false);
      setInitialLoad(false);
    });
  
    socket.on('productosActualizados', () => {
      fetchData(1, categoryId); // Recargar los datos cuando se actualizan
    });
  
    socket.on('error', (err) => {
      setError(err);
      setLoading(false);
      setInitialLoad(false);
    });
  
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [page, categoryId]);

  const fetchData = (page, category) => {
    setLoading(true);
    let url = `https://web.es/api/productos?page=${page}&limit=${limitPerPage}&api_key=my_key_cur_prod`;
    if (category) {
      url += `&category_id=${category}`;
    }
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((newData) => {
        setData((prevData) => (page === 1 ? newData.data : [...prevData, ...newData.data]));
        setLoading(false);
        setInitialLoad(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
        setLoading(false);
        setInitialLoad(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(1); // Resetear página a 1 cuando cambia categoryId
    fetchData(1, categoryId); // Obtener datos iniciales para la nueva categoría
  }, [categoryId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (page > 1) {
      fetchData(page, categoryId); // Obtener datos adicionales cuando cambia la página
    }
  }, [page]);

  const loadMore = () => {
    setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
  };

  const formatPrice = (price) => {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(price);
  };

  const handleCartClick = (productId) => {
    console.log(productId);
    fetch(`https://web.es/api/productos/${productId}/edit?api_key=my_key_cur_prod`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({}),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        const updatedData = data.map((item) => {
          if (item.id === productId) {
            // Actualiza solo el producto modificado
            return {
              ...item,
              // Puedes actualizar aquí los campos necesarios del producto
            };
          }
          return item;
        });
        setData(updatedData); // Actualiza el estado con el producto modificado
        const socket = io('http://00.000.0000:5178');
        socket.emit('productoEditado', productId);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error editing product:', error);
      });
  };
  
  
  

  if (loading && initialLoad) {
    return (
      <div className='grid_productos'>
        {[...Array(18)].map((_, index) => (
          <div key={index} className='card_mio'>
            <ProductLoader />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='grid_productos'>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={`${item.id}_${index}`} className='card_mio'>
            <div className={`stl_card ${item.estado === 2 ? 'reserva' : ''}`}>
              <div className='relative'>
                <img src={`https://web.es/${item.foto_principal}`} alt={item.name} className='img_producto'/>
                <div className='pad_info_product'>
                  <div className='flex'>
                    <div className='mr-auto'>
                      <div className='pvp'>{formatPrice(item.precio)}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex iconos_card'>
                      <span onClick={() => handleCartClick(item.id)}>
                        <FaCartPlus />
                      </span>
                      <FaRegHeart />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        ))}
        {loading && [...Array(6)].map((_, index) => (
          <div key={index} className='card_mio'>
            <ProductLoader />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <div>Cargando más...</div>
      ) : (
        <div className='text-center'>
          <button onClick={loadMore}>Cargar más</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Productos;

EL socket que he instalado en mi servidor
const http = require('http');
const axios = require('axios'); // Importa axios

const server = http.createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New client connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('getProductos', async (page, limitPerPage) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`https://web.es/api/productos?page=${page}&limit=${limitPerPage}&api_key=my_key_cur_prod`);
            socket.emit('productos', response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            socket.emit('error', error.message);
        }
    });

    socket.on('productoEditado', async (productId) => {
        // Lógica para manejar el producto editado si es necesario
        io.emit('productosActualizados'); // Emitir a todos los clientes conectados
    });

    // Puedes añadir más eventos para interactuar con tu API
});

server.listen(5178);

Bien, entonces estoy consumiendo los productos de una API. Los cargo en mi componente de React y utilizo el infiniy scroll para no tener que cargar todos los productos ya que son muchos.
Entonces cuando le doy al botón del carrito, se conecta a la API para editar el estado del producto, y cambia su estado de un 1 a un 2
<span onClick={() => handleCartClick(item.id)}>
  <FaCartPlus />
</span>

Entonces cuando itero los productos en mi componente si el producto tiene un estado = 2 hacemos esto:
<div className={`stl_card ${item.estado === 2 ? 'reserva' : ''}`}>....</div>

Vale, si cojo el primer producto de la lista y lo añado al carro, se refresca en todos los navegadores, pero mi problema está en si le doy a cargar más productos y le doy a un producto al carro se me reinicia el infinity scroll, me vuelve a la página 1 y no se actualiza bien.
Es como si la parte de la concatenación o bien los estado no se están manejando bien.
Es mi primera vez con React y con socket.
